# Custom object string field bind to date type

Tags: custom-object, dynamic-visualforce

I have a custom object, that has a picklist (populated from accounts SObject) and a text field (call it 'Value') that is dynamic in nature. 
Now if the user selects name from => Value field would be a textbox.
if the user selects LastViewDate, which is of type DateTime, the Value field would display a datepicker.[image]

****VF Page****

```
<apex:pageblocksectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="Default:" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="op1" >
        <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!Context_Variable__c.Default__c}" id="cBool" style="{!IF(lBoolean, 'display:block','display:none')}" />
        <input type="date" name="bday" />
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Context_Variable__c.Default__c}" type="text" id="cString" style="{!IF(lString, 'display:block','display:none')}" />
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Context_Variable__c.Default__c}" type="email" id="cEmail" style="{!IF(lEmail, 'display:block','display:none')}" />
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Context_Variable__c.Default__c}" type="tel" id="cPhone" style="{!IF(lPhone, 'display:block','display:none')}" />
        <apex:selectlist value="{!Context_Variable__c.Default__c}" size="1" id="cList" style="{!IF(lPickList, 'display:block','display:none')}" >
            <apex:selectoptions value="{!fieldValue_items}"></apex:selectoptions>
        </apex:selectlist>
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:pageblocksectionItem> `
```

**APEX**

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = desResult;
schema.DescribeFieldResult F = m.get(selectedValue).getDescribe();
fieldtype = F.getType().name();

// set field types to false initially      
lBoolean = lDate = lCurrency = lString = lEmail = lPhone = lPickList = false;
if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Boolean){ lBoolean = true; }
else if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Date || F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Datetime) { lDate = true; }
else if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency) { lCurrency = true; }
else if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.String) {lString = true; }
else if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.email) {lEmail = true; }
else if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.phone) {lPhone = true; }
else if (F.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.pickList) {
    lPickList = true; 
}
}
```

Comment: Is your problem how to get the part of the VF page you show re-rendered when the Fields select list changes?

Comment: I don't think SF supports "dynamic" field types. For each purpose you need to have certain field types (Checkbox, Picklist, Date, etc.).

Comment: @KeithC: My problem is- as you can see that I have fields defined in my VF page, but they are hidden, and proper typed field gets visible on the selection of 'Fields' picklist, except date type. any ideas? I had HTML5 input date type working but I want to know whether apex native date type can be used instead.

Comment: Then the problem is what mast0r says: the Visualforce date picker is only displayed if the underlying field is of type Date. So you need a date SObject field somewhere to use just for the UI and you can copy the resulting date to/from the Default__c text field somewhere in your controller.

Comment: Ok, lets say I bind my inputField to a dateField if the selected fieldType is 'Date', but how would I be able to copy the value from VF to controller? I would like to bind the value of the date field to a text field (which you might have already guessed is dynamic).

Comment: You would need your controller to expose an instance (e.g. "new Contact()") of the object with the date field and then bind that (e.g. "{!c.Birthdate}" to the apex:inputField. Your controller would then format that date as a string and copy it into Context_Variable__c.Default__c.